# Separation between components doesn't change when screen resolution changes. Why?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have created a form in Swing with 10 components (5 labels and 5 textfields), using Gridbaglayout.

When my screen resolution changes, the separation between the components is not changing. Why?

Comment: *"(5 labels and 5 textfields)"*  It seems like [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) might be a better choice for this GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridBagLayout uses pixels as the unit of measure. You can use [java.awt.Toolkit.getScreenResolution()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenResolution%28%29) to get the pixel density and then scale your spacing accordingly. You also might find [java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration.getNormalizingTransform()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getNormalizingTransform%28%29) useful; it allows you to work in a coordinate system where 72 units is 1 physical inch.